# Anyone know what these all these user sessions (see post) might be?

Tags: ubuntu, users, login, session

Any time I login to my laptop, including after freshly booting my laptop there are four user sessions already.  Only the "who" command can see all four, the "w" command can only see two with sudo and one without using sudo. Here is the terminal output for the various commands with and without sudo:

```
nat@nat-XPS-15:~$ sudo who -a
[sudo] password for nat: 
           system boot  2023-09-27 07:09
           run-level 5  2023-09-27 07:09
nat      ? :1           2023-09-27 07:09   ?          2442 (:1)
nat      + pts/1        2023-09-27 07:10   .          3524

nat@nat-XPS-15:~$ who -a
           system boot  2023-09-27 07:09
           run-level 5  2023-09-27 07:09
nat      ? :1           2023-09-27 07:09   ?          2442 (:1)
           pts/1        2023-09-27 07:10              3524 id=ts/1  term=0 exit=0

nat@nat-XPS-15:~$ sudo w
07:13:08 up 3 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.13, 0.28, 0.14
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
nat      :1       :1               07:09   ?xdm?  38.07s  0.00s /usr/libexec/gd
nat      pts/1    -                07:13    0.00s  0.00s  0.00s sudo w

nat@nat-XPS-15:~$ w
09:50:08 up  2:40,  1 user,  load average: 0.23, 0.26, 0.36
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
nat      :1       :1               07:09   ?xdm?  19:23   0.00s /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session
```

I understand what the two users under sudo 2 are: its probably my desktop and terminal session.  But what are the system boot and run-level 5 sessions?  In all of the examples of the "who" command I can find on-line, who only gives system boot information when prompted with the -s tag, and I am not seeing anything like that run-level 5 session in any example regardless of tag.  These might be innocuous, but what are they, I just want to try and understand what I am looking at.  Thanks.

My system is: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: TTY `:1` is your graphical desktop and `pts/1` is probably a terminal window where you run the `sudo w` command. Please [edit] your question and make clear what exactly you think is wrong or unexpected in the command output.

Comment: Okay, I guess I am curious abut what the "system boot" and "run-level-5" are.  I know who can give the "system boot" by using the -b, but I am not seeing any examples where it ends up showing up in a -a context like that, why is that happening.  I also don't know what the "run-level-5" user is and I am not seeing anything like in any examples of the "who" command I can find online.

I am less concerned about the sessions that show up with the "w" command which you are addressing, its the extra ones under "who."  I'll happily edit the original question to these ends with some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first result I came across in google for "man who" was https://linux.die.net/man/1/who

This appears to match the manpage (`man who`) on many of my machines, including CentOS and RedHat.

It says:

```
-a, --all
  same as -b -d --login -p -r -t -T -u
```

And looking at those options:

```
-b, --boot
   time of last system boot
-d, --dead
   print dead processes
-l, --login
  print system login processes
-p, --process
  print active processes spawned by init
-r, --runlevel
  print current runlevel
-t, --time
  print last system clock change
-T, -w, --mesg
  add user's message status as +, - or ?
-u, --users
  list users logged in
```

Your "system boot" line will be becuase of `-b` and the run-level command due to `-r`

Comment: Ah, thanks!  Sorry, just not sure what I was looking at, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

"`system boot`" is the time/date of the most recent system boot.

"`Runlevel 5`" is the time/date of the system entering multi-user mode.

Comment: Thanks!  ... I upvoted by my reputation is too low for it to count, sorry :(

Comment: @natS Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it solved your problem, and might help others.